Can one use Android apps with HarmonyOS 3? If so, are there any restrictions or limitations?
Can one use Android apps with HarmonyOS 3? If so, are there any restrictions or limitations regarding which app can run, or whether running them on HarmonyOS can make them slower?

It appears from the Wikipedia pages that you should be able to run apps that work on AOSP. But you won't have Google Mobile Services, which many Android apps require.
HarmonyOS.NEXT does not provide the AOSP environment and definitely can't run any Android apps.
